# Is there a way to pull the Earnings metric with more than two decimal places precision?

Tags: adsense-api

Right now, when querying the Adsense Management API for Ad earnings over a date range,  I get a JSON array which contains an 'Earnings' metric for each day, rounded to two decimal places. There is also a 'totals' JSON object which contains the total of the all the days requested. The sum of each day's value does not match the reported total.

I suspect that the earnings for each day is rounded off to two decimal places and the accuracy lost adds up to the missing amount. Is there a way I can get the unrounded values Adsense is using to calculate the totals? Or can I somehow get more decimal places of precision in the Earnings metric.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can get greater precision reported from the API dimensions or metrics.

Not a fix but the more granular the report, the bigger rounding problem so, if you are pulling by any Dimensions you don't need removing them may help.

Answer (score 0):

One roundabout way to do is to request earnings in currency where 1 unit of that currency is a fraction of dollar. For e.g. INR (1 INR ~= 0.015 USD). And then convert that back to USD. For e.g if the actual earning is 0.003 USD, then in INR it would be reported as INR 0.19 by the API, which then you can convert back to USD using current exchange rate. It will not be 100% accurate, but at least you will be able handle very small values.
The java api call is AdSense.Reports.Generate setCurrency(java.lang.String currency);